# Changing websocket URL in Python

Tags: python, websocket

I am using the websocket-client module with python 3.7.0

**My question is how can I change the websocket URL to get different kinds of data from a webserver dynamically.**

The websocket URL works as follows (simplified):

```
URL = "wss://somedomain.com/data1ToSubscribeTo/data2ToSubscribeTo....." and so on
```

While my script is running I would like to change the URL to subscribe to different topics whenever it is needed. Something like this:

```
URL = "wss://somedomain.com/data2ToSubscribeTo/data3ToSubscribeTo"
```

A basic example of my code looks like this:

```
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://somedomain.com/data2ToSubscribeTo/data3ToSubscribeTo"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open,  on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")


def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection closed")


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

    if message == "change":
        some_method_to_change_URL()
```